Getting A Powershell Error For Command That Works In A Tutorial
I'm following a guide to learn to install Windows Server 2022 Azure edition. I'm entering a Powershell command exactly how it is in the guide. There is even a screenshot in the guide of the command and the output. But I'm getting an error.
The command is:
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.0.2.4 -DefaultGateway 10.0.2.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex

You can see the tutorial where the output shows: https://petri.com/windows-server-2022-as-a-domain-controller/
Here is a screenshot from the tutorial:
Successful command showing
The error I'm getting is:
New-NetIPAddress : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Cannot convert the
"System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.UInt32".
At line:1 char:96
... .2.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex                                      
CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-NetIPAddress], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-NetIPAddress

How is it possible that I'm entering the exact same command but getting an error when it clearly works in the tutorial?

If the computer you're running this command on has more than one NetAdapter then you'll get an array instead of a single [INT] from (Get-NetAdapter).InterfaceIndex .... ‍♂️

And BTW ... You may go back and [edit] your question to format your code properly using a [code block].

You need to specify the NetAdapter that the command is using since in the case of your command it obtains an array, so you need to specify.
You can get the Net Adapters using the following command:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object InterfaceIndex
>>

InterfaceIndex
--------------
             5

This is an example, in your case maybe there are more than one InterfaceIndex.
Once you have verified the adapter you are going to use, type the InterfaceIndex directly as shown in this command:
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.0.2.4 -DefaultGateway 10.0.2.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 5


IPAddress         : 10.0.2.4
InterfaceIndex    : 5
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet0
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Manual
SuffixOrigin      : Manual
AddressState      : Tentative
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore

IPAddress         : 10.0.2.4
InterfaceIndex    : 5
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet0
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Manual
SuffixOrigin      : Manual
AddressState      : Invalid
ValidLifetime     : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
PreferredLifetime : Infinite ([TimeSpan]::MaxValue)
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : PersistentStore

